# SQL Server Agent job: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute an SSIS package from SQL Server Agent however receiving the error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

The job itself very simple, grabbing data from a table from server A into another database from Server B. and the connection manager is OLEDB.

This job has been executed many many times in the past without any issues, but just recently this error occurred. I also have another job (SSIS package) using the same connection manager, but that job is so far so good.

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the owners of the two jobs…

Comment: Think about using a SQL login and assign specific permissions to it.